# Java JMenuItem Accelator Snow Leopard

Tags: java, jmenubar

```
about = new JMenuItem("About");
about.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A((Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutMask()))));
JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
help.add(about);
```

I was wondering why my aaccelerators were not working. I am running this in snow leopard with JavaSe-1.6 VM. They do work if I pull the menu down then try the key sequence. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 looks like an error to me.

Shouldn't it be something like

```
getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, Toolkit...getMenuShortcutMask())
```

?

i.e. getKeyStroke has 2 arguments, separated by a comma.

Using `Toolkit...getMenuShortcutMask` to get the OS dependent key is a very clever idea, by the way. I'd never thought to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ooh, I think I understand the REAL problem:

Accelerators only work when they're visible - they allow you to move through the menu by making some character in a menu item "magic".

I think what you're looking for are mnemonics. Those will fire off your menu items from anywhere when the associated key is pressed.

Common mnemonics are <kbd>Alt-F4</kbd> to kill programs (that's <kbd>Cmd-Q</kbd> for you), <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd> to save, <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to copy, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, line two isn't correct. I must have accidentally added that K :-) I was using a mnemonics before but it also had to have the menu pulled down to function. I just want a keyboard shortcut. I switched to using accelerators because that what the [OSX java doc suggests](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001909-211867-BCIBDHFJ).